# "Ouvir" diretório utilizando Java

Tags: java, diretório, listener

Estou trabalhando em uma aplicação, e preciso criar uma funcionalidade, como um método, que fique "escutando", determinado diretório. O diretório é utilizado como destino de uploads de arquivos *.xlsx.

Preciso que sempre que houver um arquivo novo, minha aplicação leia o arquivo e faça o processamento. E não tenho muita ideia e preciso de ajuda para fazer com que minha aplicação fique 'ouvindo' o diretório para fazer esse processamento sempre que um upload for realizado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `Watch Service API`.
Veja um exemplo de como fazer:

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.*;

Path dir = ...;
try {
    WatchKey key = dir.register(watcher,
                           ENTRY_CREATE,
                           ENTRY_DELETE,
                           ENTRY_MODIFY);
} catch (IOException x) {
    System.err.println(x);
}
```

Mais detalhes em http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

### Outra opção

Você pode utilizar também o [JNotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/). Talvez a implementação seja um pouco mais "simples".
Veja um exemplo em: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941869/directory-listener-in-java

Comment: Valeu @anmaia, acredito que isso me ajude, vou testar fazer ambas implementações.

Comment: Precisei realizar uma atividade parecida e funcionou normalmente, valeu.